# Detect changes in a has_one :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

ActiveRecord makes it easy to track changes to a record by providing methods like `.changed` and, if your model has a `title` attribute, an automagical `.title_changed?` method.

But this niftiness doesn't seem to extend to "attributes" created magically through associations. For example, suppose I have:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :bar, through: foo_bar_associations
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to foo
end
```

Then changing the `bar` associated with a particular `foo` doesn't show up in `foo.changed`. Moreover, no `.bar_changed?` method is automagically created.

Is there an easy way to close this gap? Can this functionality be added on, and if so how?

Answer (score -2):

Check out the touch method of ActiveRecord Persistence module
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch

Is that what you were looking for?